# How to pass selected checkbox values into childcomponent with PrimeNg without using NgModel? Angular

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-forms

I have a basic app where I have a form and I am wanting to pass in selected checkbox values down to the child component, so that the checkboxes which are selected in the `p-multiSelect` on the parent are the only items that appear in the `p-dropdown` in the child.

Using `[(ngModel)]` this works for the most part except when I am patching values into the `p-multiSelect` options with data from an API. Also, this results in the following error:

> ```
> It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
> Support for using the ngModel input property and
> ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated
> in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7
>
> For more information on this, see our API docs here: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel
> ```

I haven't been able to figure out a good way to get this to work since I am passing down a selected value which seems like it does need to come from the `[(ngModel)]`. Is there a different way to pass down the select items from the `p-multiSelect` into the child component without using the ngModel?

As you will be able to see in the code, this IS working. The value is being passed down. However, if I use `patchValue()` on the form and bring this multiSelect option in from somewhere else, it does not work with the `NgModel`. I am also getting the error above because I am using `ngModel` on a `FormControlName`

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-rqace9) and code is below. I have simplified it tremendously and removed the form from the child component so it is just getting the value.

#### AppComponent.html

```
<div style="padding: 10px; border: solid black 1px">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <span>Parent Component. Multi-select, where selected items are input into child comp dropdown</span>
        <br>
        <p-multiSelect 
      [options]="statementOptions" 
      formControlName="statements" 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedStatements">
        </p-multiSelect>

        <div style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 5px; border: solid black 1px;">
            <span>Child Component, I want to receive selected items ,but am unaway how to without using ngModel</span>
            <app-select-statements [statements]='selectedStatements'>
            </app-select-statements>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### AppComponent.Ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      statements: ''
    })
  }
  statementOptions = [
    { label: 'Item1', value: 'item1' },
    { label: 'item2', value: 'item2' },
    { label: 'Item3', value: 'item3' },
    { label: 'Item4', value: 'item4' },
    { label: 'Item5', value: 'item5' },
  ];
}
```

#### SelectStatementComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-statements',
  template: `
    <div> 
      <p-dropdown 
        placeholder="Choose"
        [options]="statements"
        ></p-dropdown>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class StatementComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() statements;

  //this maps the values in order to get back the 
  //label and value as required by the PrimeNg dropdown
  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.statements) {
      this.statements = this.statements.map((s) => ({
        label: s,
        value: s
      }))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe just use the form value?
`<app-select-statements [statements]="form.get('statements').value">`

Comment: oof, can't believe I didn't even think of that. This worked as expected and did just what I was looking to do. Feel free to answer the question so I can accept and you can earn reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just use the form value?

```
<app-select-statements [statements]="form.get('statements').value">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix Reactive forms and Template driven forms. You are using reactive forms so you should not remove the `ngModel` and only use the `formControlName`. If you need to listen for `(ngModelChange)` you should instead subscribe in the constructor to the value changes in the form with `this.form.valuechanges.subscribe(...)`

See also https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/difference-between-template-driven-and-reactive-forms-angular